# I want order details also like order columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
select o.*,x.cust_name  from(
select cust_name from customer c where salesman_id IN(
select salesman_id from Orders o where ord_date ='2012-08-17'))x
```

I only got customer names but i need order columns also. i want solution in subquery

| ord_no | purh_amt | ord_date | cust_id | salesman_id | cust_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70011 | 75.29 | 2012-08-17 | 3003 | 5007 | jozy |
| 7004 | 110.5 | 2012-08-17 | 3009 | 5003 | geoff |

Answer (score -1):

if i understand what you want to achieve you need a inner join like so :

```
select ord_no,cust_name,ord_date 
  from customer c
  inner join orders o
    on (c.salesman_id = o.salesman_id)
  where o.ord_date = '2012-08-17';
```

Comment: I got answer in joins but how to write in sub-queries. that is my question

Comment: Can you provide the Structure of your 2 Tablets.That would be helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/subqueries/sql-subqueries-inventory-exercise-10.php

Comment: As you might see there is a solution on this site you posted, so it might just not be possible to get your wished solution with subqueries.